# How do I use CSS Houdini in Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, css-houdini

I would like to use CSS Houdini in a Next.js project I am building.  I have installed, via `yarn`, both the CSS Houdini package I want to use along with `css-paint-polyfill`.  I am following the webpack instructions here https://houdini.how/usage

Here is my component:

```
import 'css-paint-polyfill';
import workletURL from 'url-loader!css-houdini-lines';
import styles from './Separator.module.css';

CSS.paintWorklet.addModule(workletURL);

export default function Separator() {
  return <div className={styles.separator} />;
}
```

I am getting the dreaded

```
error - ReferenceError: window is not defined
at /home/tithos/code/web/new-tim/node_modules/css-paint-polyfill/dist/css-paint-polyfill.js:1:239
```

I tried putting the import for `css-paint-polyfill` in a useEffect, but the throw another error.  I even tried `const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'))` from https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import, but I did not know how to reference the library.

Has any one solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like CSS Paint Polyfill eagerly accesses `window`, which means it will throw an error when in an environment which has no `window`, such as server phase of Next. There are multiple things you can do.

1. Modify your `next.config.js` to stub the aforementioned module when for Webpack when `isServer` is `true`. You can follow [this page of the Next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) for this.
2. Create a dynamic component that's only imported on the client (I see you've tried this, but it should have worked, so maybe if you shared what you did in this regard, I could work out what's wrong with your approach).
3. Create an issue and send in a PR to [the repository where the Polyfill is hosted](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/css-paint-polyfill) to lazily access `window` depending on whether it's available or not.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the repo:

https://github.com/timscodebase/new-tim/blob/main/components/Separator/index.js

I would do option 3 but the code is on GoogleCode not github